# Landing page on OSX internet sharing via Wifi

Tags: macos

In OSX I can share my internet via wifi. Is there a way to redirect all the traffic from the wifi to my localhost server? In other words every connected client via wifi needs to see a specific page running on my local apache.

Answer (score 0):

The webpage that you see when connecting to a wireless network is called a [Captive Portal.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal)

There are a lot of great captive portals for linux, that could likely be run on Mac

Checkout [nodogsplash](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/wireless.hotspot.nodogsplash)

Here is one of the videos of Darren Kitchen setting up nodogsplash on a router.

http://bit.ly/1cNHrpa